# How to disable Wildfly 10 Hibernate Search module without persistence.xml file is autoconfigured Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate-search, wildfly-10

Hi everyone!

I am developing Spring Boot 1.5 app with Hibernate Search 5.5. As standalone app it is running as I expected, but I have a problem with deploying it on Wildfly 10. During deployment it is throwing an exception: `java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator not a subtype`

I want to disable Wildfly Hibernate Search implementation and provide my own prepackaged with my app.
I have found that I have to provide `wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module = none` property in in persistence.xml file. My question is how to do this without rewriting whole Spring Boot datasource autoconfiguration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found solution to force Wildfly not to load provided Hibernate Search module. I have read in Wildfly 10 documentation in chapter [Class Loading in Wildfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly?_sscc=t), about providing `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file. During building WAR file with my app I am adding this file in META-INF directory with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate.search.orm"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This configuration solved my problem and Wildfly is loading Hibernate Search packaged with my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `application.yaml`:

```
spring.jpa.properties:
    wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module: none
```

See an example of a Spring Boot application with Hibernate Search [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-demos/blob/master/hibernate-search/hsearch-elasticsearch-wikipedia/src/main/resources/application.yaml).
It does not use WildFly, though.

Comment: I have added property spring.jpa.properties.wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module=none in application.properties, but nothing changed. Seems it isn't passed to Wildfly.

Comment: Ok, well then I don't really know... I could suggest to add an almost empty `persistence.xml` with `wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module` set to `none`, and see if it works, but I suppose you tried.